# Django 1.9 - IOError at /login/

Tags: python, django

Sorry if you tried helping me when I asked this earlier. Had to delete that post because I thought the question was poorly written.

So I have a login view that when I click submit throws the Error:

```
Exception Type: IOError
Exception Value:    
[Errno 22] Invalid argument:  u"C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\mysite\\templates\\{'user': <CustomUser: coco>}"



Traceback:
C:\Users\Me\Desktop\mysite\accounts\views.py in login
40. return render('all_posts.html', {'user': request.user}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Originally my login view I had:

**return HttpResponseRedirect('/')**

instead of the current:

```
return render('all_posts.html', {'user': request.user}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

and the former sort of worked, in the since that it didn't throw any errors and directed me to the proper url. but in my template; {% if request.user.is_authenticated %} wasn't working.

So I changed it in the hopes of getting my template to display the current user's name *(Welcome, coco!)*, instead now I get this new error.

Here is my views.py

```
def login(request):
    """
    Log in view
    """
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = authenticate(username=request.POST['username'], password=request.POST['password'])
            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active:
                    django_login(request, user)
                    return render('all_posts.html', {'user': request.user}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        form = AuthenticationForm()
    return render_to_response('login.html', {
        'authenticationform': form,
    }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

base.html

```
<div class="log_bar">
<ul>
    {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
        <li>Welcome,</li>
        <li><a href="{% url 'profile' %}">{{ user.username }}</a></li>
        <li>|</li>
        <li><a href="{% url 'logout' %}">Log Out</a></li>
    {% else %}
        <li>Please</li>
        <li><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-login" href="">log in</a></li>
        <li>or</li>
        <li><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-register" href="">sign up</a></li>
    {% endif %}
</ul>
</div><!-- /.log_bar -->
```

**EDIT 1: Login Template**
login.html

```
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

<div class="modal" id="modal-login">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="login/">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                            <h3 class="modal-title">Log In</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            {{ authenticationform|crispy }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <input type='submit' class="btn btn-primary" value="Log In" />
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT 2: all_posts.html**

all_posts is empty right now. basically it just extends base.html. I'll post both.

all_posts.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT 3: urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from blog import views
from accounts.views import get_profile, login, logout, register
import accounts


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^textpost$', views.submit_textpost, name='textpost'),
    url(r'^linkpost$', views.submit_linkpost, name='linkpost'),
    url(r'^$', views.all_posts, name='all_posts'),
    url(r'^all$', views.all_posts, name='all_posts'),
    url(r'^new$', views.new_posts, name='new_posts'),
    url(r'^all/top_hour$', views.top_posts_hour, name='top_hour'),
    url(r'^all/top_day$', views.top_posts_day, name='top_day'),
    url(r'^all/top_week$', views.top_posts_week, name='top_week'),
    url(r'^all/top_month$', views.top_posts_month, name='top_month'),
    url(r'^all/top_year$', views.top_posts_year, name='top_year'),
    url(r'^all/top_beginning_of_time$', views.top_posts_all, name='top_beginning_of_time'),
    url(r'u/(?P<username>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)$', accounts.views.get_profile, name='username'),
    url(r'register$', register, name='register'),
    url(r'^profile/(?P<username>\w+/$)', get_profile, name='profile'),
    url(r'logout/$', logout, name='logout'),
    url(r'^login/$', login, name='login'),
    url(r'(?P<username>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$', views.get_sub, name='sub_url'),
    url(r'(?P<username>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)/(?P<title_slug>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$',  views.get_sub, views.title_slug, name='sub_post'),
    url(r'^comments/', include('django_comments_xtd.urls')),
]
```

**base.html full**

Side Note* In my **nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-left navbar-static-top"**, notice all the href's are empty, that's because if I try to populate them *{% url 'new_posts' %}* etc.. it will throws the same Traceback:
**'function' object is not iterable**. I don't know if it's related, but I thought I should mention. I'm not even concerning myself with that now, I don't want to get ahead of myself. I'm just trying to learn how to do proper login for now.

```
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML>
   <HEAD>
       <link rel="stylesheet"     href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/base.css' %}">
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
       <link href="assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <TITLE>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</TITLE>

</HEAD>

   <BODY>
   {% block content %}
       {% block navigation %}
   <div class="navbar-wrapper">
   <div class="post_button" style="width:58px; margin:0 auto;">
   <a href="#" class="btn btn-custom blue">Submit a Post</a>
   </div> <!-- /.post_button-->
   <div class="log_bar">
    <ul>
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
            <li>Welcome,</li>
            <li><a href="{% url 'profile' %}">{{ user.username }}</a></li>
            <li>|</li>
            <li><a href="{% url 'logout' %}">Log Out</a></li>
        {% else %}
            <li>Please</li>
            <li><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-login" href="">log in</a></li>
            <li>or</li>
            <li><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-register" href="">sign up</a></li>
        {% endif %}
    </ul>
    </div><!-- /.log_bar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-left navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav ">
        <li class="active"><a href="/">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="">All</a></li>
        <li><a href="">New</a></li
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Top<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="">hour</a></li>
          <li><a href="">24 hrs</a></li>
          <li><a href="">week</a></li>
          <li><a href="">month</a></li>
          <li><a href="">year</a></li>
          <li><a href="">beginning of time</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="">Custom Search</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
<div id="side_bar">
     <form class="navbar-form navbar-static-top navbar-right" role="search" id="navBarSearchForm">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="search_btn">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                        </button>
                    </span>
            </div>
            </form>
    </div><!-- /.side-bar -->
    <button class="btn-block" id='hideshow' value='hide/show' style="display: block; height: 100%;"></button>

    {% include 'register.html' %}
    {% include 'login.html' %}

    {% endblock %}

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js">    </script>
    <script  src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"> </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }} /static/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }} /static/jquery.leanModal.js"></script>

{% endblock %}
   </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: In your `render` call you probably want just the user _name_ instead of the entire user _object_.  Try `{'user': request.user.name}` instead.

Comment: Okay, so I'm getting somehwere. I changed it to: `{'user': request.user.username}` and now it's throwing the error: `TemplateDoesNotExist at /login/
{'user': u'coco'}` I'm confused as to why it would think my user is a template.

Comment: Are you sure that `.username` is the correct attribute?

Comment: Yeah, I don't have a field called 'name ' in my CustomUser model. I tried `{'user': request.user.name}` first and it gave me: `AttributeError at /login/
'CustomUser' object has no attribute 'name'`

Comment: Actually I think I was wrong.  The template is expecting the whole user object, because it has stuff like `{{user.username}}`.

Comment: Yeah, when i go resort back to `{'user': request.user}` I get that error: `IOError at /login/`

Comment: So the error happens when you click submit on the login page?  Can you post that template?

Comment: The login template was built as a modal, so in my base.html I have: `{% include 'login.html' %}` I edited the original post to include the login.html

Comment: Can you also post the `all_posts.html` template?

Comment: Sure, all_posts.html is empty right now. basically it just extends base.html.

Comment: Then I'm stumped.  It seems like it's trying to grab the username and use it as part of the html template name.  But the render call is clearly using a fixed template name of `all_posts.html`.

Comment: Oh well, thanks for taking your time to help. It's good to have a fresh pair of eyes to look at the code and infuse new ideas. it helps clear out the cobwebs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument of [render](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) must be `request object`, second template name, third context.

```
return render(request, 'all_posts.html', {'user': request.user})
```

Comment: Thanks allot Sergey. That got rid of the Errno 22. But the view still isn't working properly. Here's the full Traceback: http://dpaste.com/2MZSRTR For some reason it's saying my `{% extends "base.html" %}` isn't iterable.(if I'm reading the Traceback correctly)

Comment: Show me complete `base.html` and `urls.py`